# get an array with all values of a specific variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I would like to know how to get all the value of a specific information. In this case, I want to get all the 'name' of a message and convert it in an array. Example of message:

```
"xxxxxxxxxx name:yyyy; xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx name:yyyyy;"
```

Code (I only got the first 'name'):

```
 for i in range(0,len(message)):  
     start = message.find('name') + 4
     end = message.find(';', start)
     a=message[start:end]
     split=a.split(';')
  print(split)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `str.find`, you should provide a starting position for `start`, like you did for `end`, e.g. the previous `end` or `0` in the first iteration. Then, continue until `start` is `-1`, i.e. not found.

```
end = 0
while True:
    start = message.find('name', end)
    if start == -1:
        break
    end = message.find(';', start)
    a = message[start + 5 : end]
    print(start, end, repr(a))
```

Or you could `split` the message at whitespaces and use a conditional list comprehension:

```
>>> [s[5:-1] for s in message.split() if s.startswith("name")]
['yyyy', 'yyyyy']
```

In practice, however, I would recommend using regular expressions as shown in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49645783/1639625).

Answer (score 5):

Using regex:

```
import re
s = "xxxxxxxxxx name:yyyy; xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx name:yyyyy;"
print(re.findall(r"name:[a-zA-Z]+", s))
```

**Output:**

```
['name:yyyy', 'name:yyyyy']
```

Comment: You could also use lookbehind and lookahead: `r"(?<=name:).*?(?=;)"`, and in case the region boundaries are also relevant, better use `finditer` to get the full groups.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic almost works, you can change it to:

```
message = "xxxxxxxxxx name:yyyy; xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx name:zzzzzz;"

start = message.find('name')      # find first start
stop = message.find(';', start)   # find first stop after first start
names = []                        # all your found values get appended into this

while -1 < start < stop: # ensure start is found and stop is after it
    names.append(message[start+5:stop]) # add 5 start-pos to skip 'name:' and slice value
                                        # from message and put into names

    start = message.find('name',stop)   # find next start after this match
    if start == -1:                     # if none found, you are done
        stop = -1
    else:
        stop = message.find(';', start) # else find the end for this start

if start != -1:     # if your last ; is missing, the while above will find 
                    # start but no stop, in that case add all from last start pos to end
    names.append(message[start:])

print ( names)
```

Output:

```
['yyyy', 'zzzzzz']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def formatFunction(x):
    index_of_name = x.index('name')
    if index_of_name >= 0:
        return x[index_of_name:]
    else:
        return None

message_list = message.split(';')
message_list = message_list.map(formatFunction)
formated_list = [x for x in message_list if x]
print(formated_list)
```